# Multiple fragments in the same space?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am developing an Android app with fragments that has many possible flows. With simple `Activity`-based flow, it can flow like this:

A -> B -> E
A -> C -> E
A -> D -> E

With fragments, I would like to be able to do this same thing with a screen split into thirds. The question that I am asking is: in my layout XML file, how do I represent a space that may be filled with one of three different fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`FragmentTransaction.add()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29) function:

> `public abstract FragmentTransaction add (int containerViewId, ... )`
>   ...
>    `containerViewId` - Optional identifier of the container this fragment is to be placed in. If 0, it will not be placed in a container.

In other words, just create any empty `GroupView` in your xml layout and pass id of this group into this function when adding the fragment. Then remove it when you don't want it anymore.

Comment: I just looked at the Android Developer Documentation and it looks like that's how it should be done. Does this also work with the v4 compat library (I want to support API8 and higher)?

Answer (score 1):

If you won't need to replace fragments in your activity, you can put the fragment declaration directly inside the XML.

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.mypackage.ui.MyFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myfragment_Fragment">
</fragment>
```